# Direct limit of injective sheaves of abelian groups on noetherian topological space is injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be noetherian topological space and let ${I_\alpha}$ be direct system of injective sheaves of abelian groups on $X$.
This is question 2.6 of chapter 3 of Hartshorne. Hint given in the book is as follows-
First show that a sheaf $I$ is injective if and only if for every open set $U$ $\subset$ $X$ , and for every subsheaf $R$ $\subset$ $Z_U$, and for every map $f:R \rightarrow I$ ,there exist an extension of $f$ to a map of $Z_U$ $\rightarrow$ $I$ .

I tried to prove by Zorns lemma. But I am not able to show that maximal element is the required extension. Please someone help.

Edit- This is how I approached the problem .

Let $i$ be the inclusion of sheaf $F$ in sheaf $G$ and $f$ be morphism from sheaf $F$ to $I$. Let $A$ = {$f’$:$ F’ \rightarrow I$ | $F \subseteq F’ \subseteq$ $G$ }. By Zorns lemma family $A$ has maximal element. Let the maximal element be $f’$:$F’$ $\rightarrow$ $ I$ .  Can someone help me to show that $F’$ is in fact $G$.

Comment: Please add your work: specifically, where did your attempt break down?

Comment: I have written down my approach.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've really tried much, to be honest. If you want to show that $F'=G$, a natural place to start is to consider how they might be different, paying special attention to how that might interact with the property described in the hint.